# Find lat/lon within a radius from multiple known centered points in R

Tags: r, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am student looking at eBird data to eventually try to geospatially map bird abundance in relation to the location of coal-burning power plants. I am a beginner R user so I apologize in advance for improper question formatting and any basic questions I may ask.

My question was generated after looking at [Find lat/lon within a radius from a known centered point in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775654/find-lat-lon-within-a-radius-from-a-known-centered-point-in-r/45776344#45776344). This is the code I have generated from looking at the linked question and answer from @alistaire

```
geo_filtered_data <- my_fulldata %>% filter(latitude < 41.4167 & latitude > 35.35 & longitude > -92.5 & longitude < -88.1667)

coord <- cbind(geo_filtered_data$longitude, geo_filtered_data$latitude)

#Rush Island Power Plant: Lat = 38.126862, Long = -90.284332
#New Madrid Power Plant: Lat = 36.513599, Long = -89.574959
#Sioux Energy Center: Lat = 38.915840, Long = -90.290940
#Meramec Power Plant: Lat = 38.404560, Long = -90.340721

coord_within_5km <- data.frame(coord, 
                   within_5km = geosphere::distHaversine(
                     coord, 
                     c(-90.284332, 38.126862)) / 1000 < 5)

table(coord_within_5km$within_5km)
```

I then filtered the coord_within_5k data to only include TRUE points

```
coord_within_5km <- coord_within_5km %>% filter(within_5km == TRUE)
```

How can I edit the code to find points within 5 km of each of the power point coordinates I included. I am in-visioning a table with a column for each central coordinate and the points that are within the desired distance listed in their appropriate column.

Comment: `coord_within_5km[, coord_within_5km$coord=TRUE]`

Comment: I got this error message: 

Error: unexpected '=' in "coord_within_5km[, coord_within_5km$coord="

The code I ended up using is in the edited question now. Your comment helped stimulate some ideas which allowed me to figure it out so thank you.

Comment: can you copy your expected output?